# how to pop display a modal upon click of a button nested in a loop

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli

i'm trying to target   buttons in the loop. each button upon click is supposed to pop up a modal with details unique to that particular invoice. but my code seem to getting only the first invoice when any of the button is clicked.

```html
this is the loop with the modal



<?php
require 'connect.php'; 
require 'header.php'; 
 

?>


  <!-- modal -->

  <div class="modal fade print" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">

    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content row" id="print">
        <address>
            <img src="small.png"><br/>
            #32 Adelabu Street,Uwani,Enugu<br/>
            Phone: 08045454554
          </address>
        <address>
            Date:
          </address>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Customer Name</th>
              <th>Product name</th>
              <th>Quantity</th>
              <th>price</th>
              <th>total</th>
              <th>amount paid</th>
              <th>balance</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="details">
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>

              <td></td>



            </tr>

          </tbody>

        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="printarea">
    <table class="table table-bordered">

      <tbody class="details">
        <?php  
                            $get_invoice = "SELECT * FROM invoice ORDER BY id DESC";
                            $invoice_query = mysqli_query($connect,$get_invoice);
                            $invoice_rows = mysqli_num_rows($invoice_query);
                            while($full_rows=mysqli_fetch_array($invoice_query)) {?>
        <tr>
          <!-- the php code inside the id bracket is supposed to generate a unique id for each loop-->
          <td><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $full_rows['identify']; ?>" id="but<?php echo $full_rows['name']; ?>"></td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $full_rows['date']; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $full_rows['name']; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $full_rows['goods_description']; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $full_rows['quantity']; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $full_rows['price']; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $full_rows['total']; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $full_rows['amount_paid']; ?>
          </td>

          <td>
            <?php echo $full_rows['balance'] ?>
          </td>
          <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="print"></td>
          <td><input type="button" value="delete" id="add" class="btn btn-danger"></td>

          <!-- the unique id generated is passed inside the onclick function to target specific invoice in the modal-->
          <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modaSS" data-target=".print" onclick="modal('but<?php echo $full_rows['name'];?>')" id="view">View</button></td>


          <!--DISPLAYING MODAL WITH INVOICE DETAILS-->
          <script type="text/javascript">
            function modal(invoice) {
              var identify = $("[id^='but']").val();
              var dataString = 'identify=' + identify;
              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "modal.php",
                data: dataString,
                //cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                  alert(html);
                }
              });
              return false;
            }
          </script>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
      </tbody>

    </table>
  </div>

  </div>
```

```html
this is the this is where the ajax request is been proccessed


<?php

$identify = $_POST['identify'];
//connecting to server and selecting database
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','sidney');

if (isset($_POST['identify'])) {
  $select = "SELECT * FROM `invoice` WHERE identify='$identify'";
  $query = mysqli_query($connect,$select);
  $get_number = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  if ($get_number) {
    echo $get_number['identify'];
    return $get_number['identify'];
  }else{
    echo "There was trouble locating the number";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Add your code please so that we can help in better way with practical . :)

Comment: true, i just updated it

Comment: you can use data attribute to get the data when mode opens. @dmoxy

Comment: i appreciate the answer, but the problem is that when the modal pops up, it only shows the first invoice, no matter the one you selected

Comment: Maybe the error is caused by the VIEW button -> in your loop, all buttons have the same ID "view" -> this is not valid html, can cause errors with js/jquery

Comment: note that, i deliberately mispelt the data -toggle value, because i was thinking retrieving a unique value from the hidden input tag and tie it to each invoice, and use it o display details particular to that unique invoice. problem is that it only retrieves the first invoice unique number no matter the button you click

Comment: Also, have you tried to debug the js? Use a "console.log(identify);" before the "$.ajax" part to check what are you getting. Plus, why is the same js function inside that while loop?..

Comment: the button onclick function carries a unique paramater which ties it to a particular invoice when the event is executed @verjas

Comment: Why do you need a hidden input? Why can't you put the "identify" inside the button directly: onclick="modal('<?php echo $full_rows['identify']... ?>')"

Comment: the value i get from the input is condition for the select query when getting details from database @verjas

Comment: @dmoxy I rolled back your question. If you have a new question, ask a new question. Don't edit an old one. Also, the question you tried to ask is too opinion based, you are better off on google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this I have just given the idea of how should you can open model and send data to the opened model:

```
 //Your Button HTML
<button type="button" class="your_next_button_class btn btn-warning" 
data-name="<?php echo $full_rows['name'];?>" 
data-toggle="modaSS" data-target=".print" id="view">View</button>

$('body').on('click', '.your_next_button_class', function(e) {

    var name = $(this).data('name');
    //As abouve example you can get any data using data arrribute
    // Now You can open a model on the same page you don't need to send data

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "modal.php",
        data: dataString,
        //cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
        // Here in response you get the $get_number['identify']; data.
          alert(response);

        //Now To Send this response to the model
        // If you are adding this value to hidden input then
        $('.hidden_input_class').val(response);

       // Or you for display this in as text
        $('.your_class_where_want_to_display').text(response);


          // THis is how you open the model
          $('.your_model_class').modal('show');

        }
      });
});
```

I am assuming that your query correct and valid data to ajax success.

Comment: do you have any idea how i can make each modal pop up with unique invoice details?

Comment: are You need to send the invoice id to each model ? @dmoxy

Comment: yeah, the logic is that when the view button is clicked, it should trigger a select query from database where for instance where unique_id = $indentifyer. the identifyer variable will be the value gotten from the hidden input tag because it is unique to all invoice